# How to replace the value of a property object with an array (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I’m using powershell to update my appsettings.json. I have an array, which I want to replace in the property of my appsettings.json for it. Here are the steps I follow:

1. get an array of values (done),
2. transform the appsettings into a powershell object (done),
3. compare if the values of 1 and the property inside of the appsettings are similar (done),
4. if different, I want to replace the part in appsettings with my values from 1. This is the part I’m having issues with.

My appsettings looks like this (below). My intention is to replace stuff and stuff2 with values from 1

```
{
“Key1” : “value1”,
“Key2” : [
 “Stuff”,
 “Stuff2”
]
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add code that shows what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell allows us to manipulate json objects the same way we would manipulate any other object.
So the following would work

```
$array = "Stuff3", "Stuff4"
$json = Get-Content .\appsettings.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Key2 = $array
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content .\appsettings.json
```